# Weird zsh Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: segmentation-fault, zsh

*EDIT I've separated my loops so I don't run into some weird embedded loop junk and am still getting the segfault. I've updated my code block below. Unfortunately, adding the echo doesn't work anymore, so I can't ever make it to my "I made it!" echo command.*

I have a shell script that takes files from the arguments of the script, separates them into videos and image sequences, then adds them to a list. This list is later passed to ffmpeg for batch encoding. The weird thing is, the loop I have setup to do this gives "Segmentation Fault 11" unless I add an echo statement at the beginning of the loop. Check it out:

```
## Build list of files to encode, using only files from approved extensions list.
argument_files=()
filelist=()

echo "Building file list."
for argument in $@; do
    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    argument_files+=($(find "$argument" -type f | grep -e ".*/.*\.\($filters)"))
    IFS=$OLDIFS
done

for thisfile in $argument_files; do
    echo $thisfile
    if [[ "$thisfile" =~ .*\.($sequence_exts) ]]; then
        has_sequences="y"
        inlist="n"
        tempdir=$(dirname "$thisfile")
        tempext=$(basename "$thisfile" | sed 's/.*\.\(.*\)/\1/')
        tempname=$(basename "$thisfile" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')
        collection=$(echo "$tempname" | sed 's/[0-9]*$//')
        chartemp=$(echo "$tempname" | grep -o -m 1 -e '[0-9]*$')

        if [[ "$chartemp" != [0-9]* ]]; then
            continue
        fi

        charcount=`printf "%02d" ${#chartemp}`
        new_path="${tempdir}/${collection}%${charcount}d.${tempext}"

        for e in ${filelist[@]}; do
            if [[ "$e" == "$new_path" ]]; then
                inlist="y"
                break
            fi
        done

        if [[ "$inlist" == "n" ]]; then
            OLDIFS=$IFS
            IFS=$'\n'
            filelist+=("$new_path")
            IFS=$OLDIFS
        fi

    elif [[ "$thisfile" =~ .*\.($mov_exts) ]]; then
        OLDIFS=$IFS
        IFS=$'\n'
        filelist+=("$thisfile")
        IFS=$OLDIFS
    fi
done

echo "I made it!"
```

Just so you know, the first if statement is used to filter out image sequences and convert them to the format that ffmpeg wants name%0Nd.jpg. It also tries to make sure that that same image sequence hasn't already been added to the batch list. This feels really hacky to me. Apologies if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `zsh` is throwing a segfault, that's an indication of something very wrong with zsh itself (although there's a slight possibility of bad memory leading to the segfault).

You may want to check for a `zsh` update.  Or look for a replacement (perhaps pdksh or bash).

No script mistake should ever cause the shell to segfault.

Comment: That's good to know! If the error weren't happening on two of my machines I would blame memory. In the end, I fixed my syntax up for bash and things started working great. Thanks!